# Which number is greater A or B?

Tags: inequality, products, trigonometric-integrals, constants

Let :

$$I_k=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{y}{4n^{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)dy$$

And :

$$h\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\operatorname{floor}\left(x\right)}\left(1+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{y}{n^{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)dy$$

$$m\left(x\right)=x^{2}\left(h\left(x\right)-h\left(x-1\right)\right)$$

Now if we have :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}m(x)=A,\lim_{k \to \infty}I_k=B$$

> > Which number is bigger meaning : $A\leq B$ or $B\leq A$? A numerical approach is accepted.

---

---

As attempt we have using Fatou's lemma :

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}I_k\geq \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{y}{4n^{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)dy$$

Or as the product is decreasing :

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{y}{4n^{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)dy\geq \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\arctan\left(\left(\frac{y}{4k^{2}}\right)\right)\right)\right)^{k^2}dy$$

Which leads us to as lower bound :

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{\frac{y}{4}}dy\simeq 1.1360...$$

Where we have used for $x\in[0,1]$and $k\geq 6$ :

$$\left(1+\arctan\left(\frac{x}{k^{2}}\right)\right)^{k^{2}}-\prod_{n=1}^{k}\left(1+\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)\right)\leq 0$$

For the other limit $m(x)$ see my answer which use Am-gm here [What is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}[g(x)-g(x-1)]\overset?=$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626179/what-is-lim-limits-x-to-inftygx-gx-1-overset)

Comment: A simple use of $\arctan(x)\leq x$ and Euler product and we got $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\sinh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\pi\sqrt{x}}dx>\lim_{k \to \infty}I_k$$

Comment: $$\lim_{k \to \infty}I_k <\frac {16}{\pi^2} \sinh ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$ is very interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning
$$I_k=\int_0^1 \left(\prod _{n=1}^k \left(1+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{4
   n^2}\right)\right)\right) \, dy$$ we have
$$\log \left(1+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)=\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac {a_p}{z^p}$$ where the first cefficients are
$$\left\{1,-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{15},-\frac{4}{45}
   ,-\frac{1}{45},\frac{43}{840},\frac{64}{2835},-\frac{409}{94
   50},-\frac{71}{4725},\frac{1744}{51975}
   \right\}$$

Let $y=4x$
$$\log \left(1+\tan ^{-1}\left(1+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right)=\sum_{p=1}^\infty a_p\,\frac {x^p}{n^{2p} }$$

Summing the logarithms we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\,x^i\,H_k^{(2 i)}$$

Exponentiating, the integrand write
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i\,x^i$$ and the integral is
$$I_k=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{b_i}{4^i\,(i+1)}$$ The only trouble is that the $b_i$ are too messy to be reported here (they are fully explicit).

Truncating the first summation to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{22}}\right)$,  some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 10^0 & 1.123729421 & 1.123729419 \\
 10^1 & 1.206505449 & 1.206505447 \\
 10^2 & 1.220207920 & 1.220207918 \\
 10^3 & 1.221659227 & 1.221659226 \\
 10^4 & 1.221805201 & 1.221805200 \\
 10^5 & 1.221819807 & 1.221819806 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

With regard to $m(x)$, some numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & m(x) \\
 10^1 & 1.12367406 \\
 10^2 & 1.20306738 \\
 10^3 & 1.21094395\\
 10^4 & 1.21173079\\
 10^5 & 1.21180947 \\
 10^6 & 1.21181730 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Computing as accurately as I could
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & I_x & m(x) & I_x - m(x)\\
 10^1 & 1.2065054471392 &   1.1236740645233 & 0.0828313826159 \\
 10^2 & 1.2202079184296 &   1.2030673798440 & 0.0171405385857 \\
 10^3 & 1.2216592256396 &   1.2109439498962 & 0.0107152757434 \\
 10^4 & 1.2218051998498 &   1.2117307913530 & 0.0100744084969 \\
 10^5 & 1.2218198057389 &   1.2118094671503 & 0.0100103385886 \\
 10^6 & 1.2218212664125 &   1.2118173346463 & 0.0100039317662 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Do you think there are equal ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. What equal what ?

Comment: With your work do we have $A=B$ ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. A new challenge for you : prove or disprove that $I_x-m(x) > \frac 1 {100}$. Cheers :-)